# get invoice id from a Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice object

Tags: php, magento, observer-pattern, invoice

I'm writing an observer for the sales_order_invoice_register event, I'd like to get the invoice number that has just saved. I can't find the function for retrieving that ID, none of those commented calls works. Any idea?
Here the code

```
public function foobar($observer){

      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      $id_order = $order->getRealOrderId();
      $id_invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice(); // the Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice object
      //$id_invoice = $id_invoice->getId();                                                                                                         
      //$id_invoice = $id_invoice->getIncrementId();                                                                                                            
      //$id_invoice = $id_invoice->getInvoiceId();                                                                                                           
      //$id_invoice = $id_invoice->getRealIncrementId();                                                                                               
      //$id_invoice = $id_invoice->getData('invoice_id');
```

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a `var_dump($id_invoice->getData());` to see if it gives anything helpful?

Comment: [no there isn't anything useful](http://pastebin.com/XhpZ81Ms) :(

Comment: I just took a quick peak at the Invoice model, and it's possible that the object hasn't been saved yet when that event is called so it doesn't have an ID. What were you needing the ID for? Maybe I can help figure out a work around.

Comment: I just need the order and the invoice id for bureaucracy reasons. The action should be fired immediately after the invoice has been created. I'm trying different event name now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this was a while ago, but in case someone still needs help on this, hopefully the following will be of use.

Once in your observer method, use the following code to get invoice ID.

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
$invoice_id = $invoice->getData('entity_id');  // or you could also use ->getEntityId();
```

You can check out the **sales_flat_invoice** table in the Mage db (ID is the first field with the name 'entity_id').  Once you have the $invoice object, similar to any other object that inherits from the **Varien_Object** class, you can use Magento's `getData()` method to access attribute values.

Also, need to look at a different event possibly... the sales_order_invoice_register event returns "unknown" according to Mage docs.  Try the `sales_order_invoice_pay` event for the above code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the event "sales_order_invoice_save_after" in the config.xml and in your observer.php : `$observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();`